# Typescript, React and Redux axios Error - actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Need some Help With Typescript, React and Redux.

```js
export function fetchAllMeals (subject: string){
  axios 
  .get(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${subject}`)
  .then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return { type: FETCH_ALL_MEALS, data: response.data };
    }
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

I keep getting this error is `actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions`

Or when I do:

```js
export function fetchAllMeals (subject: string): MealActionTypes {
  axios 
  .get(`https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${subject}`)
  .then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.data)
    return { type: FETCH_ALL_MEALS, data: response.data };
    }
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Or this error is `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.` - I have changed `: MealActionTypes` in top line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In redux, all the actions should be synchronous. However in your case you are doing an http call with `axios` and so it is an asynchronous operation.

The error message that you get `actions must be plain objects. use custom middleware for async actions` is then correct.

So if you want to do async actions, you need to use a async middleware. The easiest one is [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)